# Always Allow Native DB Queries

Tags: excel, excel-2013, powerquery

In Excel 2013 how can I change options (or is it possible) to always allow native DB Queries?

Can someone walk me through how to set this up?

Comment: Why down vote me?  Add some insight as I know if something missed.

Comment: As a secondary note, I am not the down voter, however for general Excel help I would steer away from SO as if you read stackoverflow.com/tour it states: "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers..."

Comment: Though it could be worded better, it appears to be a professional development question, not general Excel how-to. Power Query has some prompts that are a bit tricky to get around but developers need to understand so solutions can be distributed to users.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When in Excel
1) Click Power Query from the "Ribbon" across the top
2) Choose Options 
3) From the Options Window that loads select Security from the left
4) Untick the box that says "Require user approval for new native database queries"
5) Click OK

Comment: Is there a way to set this setting via VBA?

Comment: VBA record macro it

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but I am unable to find something that is labelled *Power Query* in my entire Ribbon.

Comment: It would be better to specify which version of Excel. This answer doesn't work for me on the latest version of Excel 365 running on Windows 10 in Dec 2021. The answer below from Cody Myers seems to be better.

Answer (score 11):

I don't yet have a high enough reputation to comment this on user2676140's answer, but to piggyback off of it in case anyone comes to this thread for Excel ***2016*** instead, this option is in:

1. "Data" Ribbon
2. "Get & Transform" Group
3. "New Query" drop-down
4. "Query Options"
5. "Security" section
6. Untick the box that says "Require user approval for new native database queries" and click OK

If I find a VBA solution I'll post it as well.

**Edit:** To *bypass* the alert in VBA, although technically it isn't unticking the box for you, use the following:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'Run your code to execute the query
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also update the Windows registry to achieve this behavior, as suggested by one of the posts in this [forum topic](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c91e954c-22a2-4b2b-b7c3-e26cbde68ac0/suppress-power-querys-native-database-query-warning?forum=powerquery).

> Creating a DWORD value with the name DisableNativeDbQueryPrompt and
>   setting the value to 1 will disable native query prompts.
>
> The registry path for the PQ add-in:
>
> 32-bit (on a 64-bit system):
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft Power
>   Query for Excel
>
> 64-bit (or 32-bit on a 32-bit system):
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft Power Query for Excel
>
> For Office 2016:
>
> 32-bit (on a 64-bit system):
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Office\16.0\PowerQuery
>
> 64-bit (or 32-bit on a 32-bit system):
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\PowerQuery